# Azure Web PubSub browser client not receiving messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-web-pubsub

I am trying to use Azure Web PubSub to send messages to a browser from a Node app running o na server.  I send messages to a group via the Node app, and in the Azure Cloud shell I can see that the messages can be received by the Azure CLI.  But the browser client receives no messages whatsoever.

Is there anything else I can check to see why the Azure CLI in the cloud shell is receiving messages and my browser client is not?

**Node server app code snippet** (running locally on my dev machine)

```
const hub = 'myHub';
const key = new AzureKeyCredential('<valid Azure Web PubSub key>');
const service = new WebPubSubServiceClient('https://mydomain.webpubsub.azure.com', key, hub);
const groupClient = service.group('pubsubGroup');

// ..

let msg = 'some text';
groupClient.sendToAll({ messsage: msg }).then(() => {
   console.log(msg);
});
```

**Browser client code** (in web page running locally, http://localhost:5000)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            (async function () {
                // get token from local node web backend
                let res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/getPubSubUrl');
                let data = await res.json();
                let ws = new WebSocket(data.url, 'json.webpubsub.azure.v1');
                ws.onopen = () => {
                    // this code is always reached
                    console.log('connected');
                };

                ws.onclose = () => {
                    // this code is never reached, no premature socket closures
                    console.log('socket closed');
                }

                let output = document.querySelector('#container');

                ws.onmessage = event => {
                    // this code is only called once with a system message when the socket connects, never after
                    let d = document.createElement('p');
                    d.innerText = event.data;
                    output.appendChild(d);
                };
            })();            
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Node Express web backend to serve PubSub token URL**

```
let cnxn = '<valid connection string from Azure Portal>';
let service = new WebPubSubServiceClient(cnxn, 'myHub');

App.get('/getPubSubUrl', async (req, res) => {
    let token = await service.getClientAccessToken({
        roles: ['webpubsub.sendToGroup.pubsubGroup', 'webpubsub.joinLeaveGroup.pubsubGroup']
    });
    res.send({
        url: token.url
    });
});
```

**Azure Cloud Shell Commands and output**

```
myuser@Azure:~$ az webpubsub client start --name "<valid pubsub resource>" --resource-group "<valid resource group>" --hub-name "myHub"
joingroup pubsubGroup
{"type":"message","from":"group","fromUserId":null,"group":"pubsubGroup","dataType":"json","data":{"messsage":"valid message from my node server app!"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I missed one step which was documented elsewhere but does not exist (as far as I can tell) in any of the standard examples.  Just having a URI generated from the roles tied to the group is not enough, you must send a web socket string message to the uri asking to join the group explicitly:

in the web page script:

```
ws.onopen = () => {
    console.log('connected');

    // need to explicitly join the group!
    let ackId = 0;
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: 'joinGroup',
        group: 'pubsubGroup',
        ackId: ++ackId
    }));
};
```